# How to do early stopping with tensorflow.models.Sequential()?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

Using a sequential model generated like this:

```
def generate_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=10, strides=1,
                     activation='relu', padding='same',
                     input_shape=(MAXLENGTH, NAMESPACELENGTH)))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4, strides=2))
    model.add(Conv1D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=4))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', 
                  optimizer='adam', metrics=['mean_squared_error'])
    return model
```

I want to do Kfold cross-validated modeling. So, I train K models in a loop:

```
models = []
for ndx_train, ndx_val in kfold.split(X, y):
    model = generate_model()
    N_train = len(ndx_train)
    X_batch = X[ndx_train]
    y_batch = y[ndx_train]
    model.fit(X_batch, y_batch, epochs=100, verbose=1, steps_per_epoch=10,
             validation_data=(X[ndx_val], y[ndx_val]), validation_steps=100)

    models.append(model)
```

Now, I can see when I want each model to stop by looking at the output. I.e. when the validation error increases again. Is it possible to do that easily with pure `tf` and with this higher level api setup? There is some suggestions using along the lines using `tflearn` [here](http://mckinziebrandon.me/TensorflowNotebooks/2016/11/20/early-stopping.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [EarlyStopping](https://keras.io/callbacks/#earlystopping) callback:

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
callbacks = [
    EarlyStopping(monitor='val_mean_squared_error', patience=2, verbose=1),
]
model.fit(..., callbacks=callbacks)
```